# quickfixj (mvn quickfix-all 2.2.0) fix44 client onMessage only receiving part of the message for MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh

Tags: quickfixj

I'm having trouble parsing market data from a fix source. Seems like I'm only getting the first of every item of every MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh? Here's my Application main code, there's nothing special here:

```
    @Override
    public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
        crack(message, sessionID);
    }
    
    public void onMessage(quickfix.fix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, UnsupportedMessageType, IncorrectTagValue {
        logger.info(String.format("[MARKET_DATA_SNAPSHOT_FULL_REFRESH (RAW)] %s => %s", sessionID, message));
    }
```

Here's what I see in the logs. I can clearly see that I'm getting more than 1 item per msg at FIXMessageDecoder, but bizarrely once it reaches onMessage it's been cut down to only the first item and NoMDEntries (268) has been set to 1. These are the ONLY log entries for 34=46. I cleaned up the artifacts so it is more readable.

```
2020-11-09 14:58:38 DEBUG FIXMessageDecoder:223 - parsed message: pos=576,lim=576,rem=0,offset=576,state=4 8=FIX.4.4 9=553 35=W 34=46 49=FIX_API_29_PRICES 52=20201109-06:58:36.772 56=PRICES_FIX_API_29 55=EUR/CAD 262=739f5cfb-889d-407c-b147-afa140532805 264=0 461=SPOT 268=6 269=0 270=1.54767 271=400000 299=1062660903557668864 272=20201112 269=1 270=1.54781 271=2100000 299=1062660903557668865 272=20201112 269=0 270=1.54765 271=4400000 299=1062660903557668866 272=20201112 269=1 270=1.54782 271=4600000 299=1062660903557668867 272=20201112 269=0 270=1.54764 271=18300000 299=1062660903557668868 272=20201112 269=1 270=1.54783 271=3500400 299=1062660903557668869 272=20201112 10=101

2020-11-09 14:58:51 INFO  FixMarketApplication:76 - [MARKET_DATA_SNAPSHOT_FULL_REFRESH (RAW)] FIX.4.4:PRICES_FIX_API_29->FIX_API_29_PRICES => 8=FIX.4.4 9=217 35=W 34=46 49=FIX_API_29_PRICES 52=20201109-06:58:36.772 56=PRICES_FIX_API_29 55=EUR/CAD 262=739f5cfb-889d-407c-b147-afa140532805 264=0 461=SPOT 268=1 269=0 270=1.54767 271=400000 272=20201112 299=1062660903557668864 10=190
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Check your data dictionary. You most likely have a mismatch between the dictionary and what your counter party is sending.

Comment: I just realized this as well and tried the FIX44.modified.xml and still no luck. I'll try asking the counterparty for more info...

Comment: Got it working! I pointed the datadictionary in the config to a custom one according the counterparty specs. Thank you

Comment: Hi Totoro, it would be good to answer you own question (not by way of comment but by an actual question).